# Why are paths of solar eclipses symmetrical around a January 2015 axis?

Tags: observational-astronomy, eclipse

My cousin, James Andrews, observed that the paths of eclipses before and after Jan 2015 form a symmetry. Here is a visual description [image: visual description]

I know there's a logical explanation, but it's been ascribed a [supernatural significance](https://www.cross2victory.com/eclipse-reversal). You'll see more of the visual description in [that link](https://www.cross2victory.com/eclipse-reversal), too.

Why are the paths symmetrical? My intuition says it has something to do with harmonics...

Comment: There are a few different eclipse cycles.  https://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/SEsaros/SEperiodicity.html

Comment: FWIW, the Saros numbers of those pairs add to 273.